# Framer-Motion with polymorphistic component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, framer-motion

I am using React.js with Typescript and the library `framer-motion`, but I don't know how to apply the `motion` object to a **polymorphistic react component**. Here's the code:

```js
import React, { DetailedHTMLProps } from 'react';

type ButtonProps = DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>;
type AnchorProps = DetailedHTMLProps<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>;

type Props = (ButtonProps | AnchorProps) & {
    as?: 'button' | 'a';
    secondary?: boolean;
};

const Button: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const Component = props.as || 'button';

    const newProps = { ...props };

    delete newProps.as;
    delete newProps.secondary;
    delete newProps.className;

    return (
        <Component
            className={
                props.secondary
                    ? `font-bold text-lg lg:mx-4 sm:mx-2 flex items-center gap-1 select-none ${props.className}`
                    : `font-bold text-lg px-4 py-2 select-none rounded-xl text-white bg-primary-base hover:bg-primary-hover mx-4 ${props.className}`
            }
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
            {...(newProps as any)}>
            {props.children}
        </Component>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

I tried doing this:

```js
import React, { DetailedHTMLProps } from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

// ...

const Button: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    // ...
    return (
        <motion.Component>
            {/* ... */
        </motion.Component>
    )
};

export default Button
```

But it doesn't seem to work, since I get this type error on `Component`:

> `Property 'Component' does not exist on type '(<Props extends {}>(Component: string | ComponentType<PropsWithChildren<Props>>, customMotionComponentConfig?: CustomMotionComponentConfig | undefined) => CustomDomComponent<...>) & HTMLMotionComponents & SVGMotionComponents'.ts(2339)`

How can I make this work?